# Helgrind and atomic_flag

Tags: c++, valgrind, atomic, spinlock

I tried the basic example of using `atomic_flag` at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_flag/). Valgrind's Helgrind tool reports

```
164 errors from 28 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

with examples such as

```
==4868== Possible data race during read of size 1 at 0x605220 by thread #3
==4868== Locks held: none
==4868==    at 0x401172: test_and_set (atomic_base.h:176)
==4868==    by 0x401172: append_number(int) (helgrind_spinlock.cpp:12)
[output deleted]
==4868== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #2
==4868== Locks held: none
==4868==    at 0x4011C9: clear (atomic_base.h:193)
==4868==    by 0x4011C9: append_number(int) (helgrind_spinlock.cpp:14)
[output deleted]
```

Is the reference in error on proper use of `atomic_flag` as a spin lock, or is Helgrind giving a false positive here?

Comment: Slight differences in the example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag  Also your link description and site destination are different from each other.

Comment: Whoops, sorry; I'll fix. I mean `cplusplus.com` but I'll check against `cppreference.com`. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardCritten The one at cppreference.com gives `17350 errors from 10 contexts`. They look like pretty much the same complaint to me; it's just that the second one has a loop and the first one doesn't.

Comment: Helgrind doesn't support modern C++ atomics, see these bugzilla items https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327881 and https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327881https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339330

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are false positive. Helgrind does not understand 'low level' synchronisation,
it only understands posix synchronisation primitives.

See user manual http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.effective-use which e.g. says:

> Make sure your application, and all the libraries it uses, use the
>   POSIX threading primitives. Helgrind needs to be able to see all
>   events pertaining to thread creation, exit, locking and other
>   synchronisation events. To do so it intercepts many POSIX pthreads
>   functions.
>
> Do not roll your own threading primitives (mutexes, etc) from
>   combinations of the Linux futex syscall, atomic counters, etc. These
>   throw Helgrind's internal what's-going-on models way off course and
>   will give bogus results.

So, waiting for helgrind to understand e.g. c++ atomic flags, you will have
to annotate the code with client requests to let helgrind "see" the
synchronisation primitives based on atomic flags.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that the STL counted as rolling one's own primitives, especially since somewhere along the way it invokes pthread's (at least in Linux). I appreciate the answer.